# Got "Error running Integrated External Tool Builder" while setting up SWIG Builder for PocketSphinxAndroidDemo

Tags: android, eclipse, swig, cmusphinx

Im setting up the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo in my Eclipse. I followed the instruction here: https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo. In step 9, in the SWIG part  its says there that "Don´t change anything in the "Main"-Tab" but an error message pop out of my eclipse "The file does not exist for the external tool named SWIG". So i change the path to C:\Users\beautifulJeazel\Documents\Project\CMUSphinx\PocketSphinxAndroidDemo.externalToolBuilders\SWIG.Launch.

After applying the changes I got this error :

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'PocketSphinxDemo'.
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\beautifulJeazel\Documents\Project\CMUSphinx\PocketSphinxAndroidDemo.externalToolBuilders\SWIG.launch" (in directory "C:\Users\beautifulJeazel\Documents\Project\CMUSphinx\PocketSphinxAndroidDemo\jni"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\beautifulJeazel\Documents\Project\CMUSphinx\PocketSphinxAndroidDemo.externalToolBuilders\SWIG.launch" (in directory "C:\Users\beautifulJeazel\Documents\Project\CMUSphinx\PocketSphinxAndroidDemo\jni"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I dont know, what seems to be the problem. I path the swig in the Environment Variables just what the tutorial says but i can't seem to make it work. I tried googling it but i can't find a definite answer for my problem.. I hope u can help with this.

im using swig-1.3.34, eclipse juno and android ndk r9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easiest build you can just check precompiled version from

https://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/pocketsphinx-android-demo

It is new updated version with new features which doesn't require SWIG and works just with importing the project.

For information about it please see the updated tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: ,Thank you, that solved my SWIG problem but another came out. The error is :"Compile thumb : pocketsphinx_jni <= pocketsphinx_wrap.c
C:/Users/beautifulJeazel/Documents/Project/CMUSphinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:751:26: fatal error: pocketsphinx.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/Users/beautifulJeazel/Documents/Project/CMUSphinx/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo//obj/local/armeabi/objs/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o] Error 1.This is my first time to use external builders, maybe u could help me out on this too?

Comment: You need to make sure you properly unpacked pocketsphinx and the path to pocketsphinx top folder in pocketsphinx/jni/Android.mk is correct

Comment: Still the same. my pocketsphinx is under the CMUSphinx Folder so my path in android.mk is SPHINX_PATH := /cygdrive/C/Users/beautifulJeazel/Documents/Project/CMUSphinx. is there something wrong in my path?Then i also noticed that the 3 files including the .so file located in PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/libs/armeabi that was generated after the ndk build in cygwin was gone/erased after i build the project in eclipse. is there any other way that can i make this work?

Comment: What version are you trying to build, is it a new one? For the new version you don not need ndk at all, it should compile just fine, are you sure you imported it properly? You probably want to cleanup old sources and just checkout new version.

Comment: I just follow the tutorial but the link given for the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo is corrupted so i get it in another source. Can u give me a link where i could download the new version? so with this new version, i don't need to do the ndk build in cygwin and the ndk builder in eclipse?

Comment: Link is in the answer

Comment: Thank very much..u help me a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

Select your project and right click Properties->Builders.

Select the offending builder and remove it.

Comment: This is not exactly helpful - the builder probably exists for a reason.